# Netlogo: Getting link assigned to a particular agent

Tags: netlogo

I have 2 agents, **hub** and **individual**.

Individuals have its own variable called **value**. Links have its own variable called **strength**.

I want to write a method that allow hub to select the individual with the highest **value** and has already established a link with the hub, in order to strengthen the link which increases the link's variable **strength**.

However, the max amount strength can reach is capped by a global variable called max_strength. If the strength amount is close to this cap. I want to choose the next best individual.

I would like to ask how can I perform this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to approach this. I'd go with:

```
ask hubs [
  let candidates my-links with [ strength < max-strength ]
  if any? candidates [
    ask max-one-of candidates [ [ value ] of other-end ] [
      set strength strength + 1 ; or whatever you want to increase it by
      if strength > max-strength [ set strength max-strength ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Whether or not `if strength > max-strength [ set strength max-strength ]` is needed depends on whether or not `max-strength` is an exact multiple of the strength increase. You could also use `set strength min (list (strength + 1) max-strength)` to achieve the same thing.